# how can i get the derived DbContext from the type of TEntity

Tags: c#, entity-framework

i have two class inherited from dbcontext

```
public class AContext : DbContext
{ 
     DbSet<A> A { get; set; }
}

public class BContext : DbContext
{
     DbSet<B> B { get; set; }
     DbSet<C> C { get; set; }
}
```

*How can i get the specified context by the typeOf(A/B/C) or typeOf(DbSet'<'A/B/C'>'))?*

Comment: EF data entities are just POCOs; there's no real association between the entity and the context. What are you trying to accomplish at this point?

Comment: I have a generic repository such as Rpository<T> and T is the entity class, now i want to get the specified dbContext by the typeof(T) in the constuctor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: you can't, in general, since it's quite possible to have an `ABContext` *and* a `BCContext` - which do you want to find from the type `B`?

If you constrain yourself to cases where the same type is never handled by multiple context types (or, at least, this is true for any type you will use as input for the search), you could just get all the types in the assembly, filter out the ones that inherit `DbContext` and that have a property of the correct type, and choose the one that matches.

```
typeof(ABContext).GetTypeInfo().Assembly.Types
    .Select(t => t.GetTypeInfo())
    .Where(t => typeof(DbContext).IsAssignableFrom(t))
    .Where(t => t.Properties.Any(p => p.Type == yourDbSetType))
    .Single();
```

(Typed on my phone, so very likely has some typos or incorrect calls to BCL functions. I'll double check when I'm at a computer...)

But what do you hope to accomplish by this? Isn't it better to have all the db sets in a single context, to avoid this need?

Comment: Thank you for the answers, i have the abstract and generic Repository<T>, and T is the entity class, and i want to use DI to inject the IAmbientDbContextLocator, and my repository has the property DataContex and return a DbContext type, now i don't know how to write the code in the getter function in the property. _contextLoactor.Get(_dbContextType); // how to get the dbcontextType?

Comment: If you're OK with exposing the db context type to the client code, you could make the repo type `Repository<T, TContext>`, which gives you all the information you need. If you don't want the client code to have to know what context type to use, just put all your db sets in one context.

Comment: ok, i would try exposing the dbcontext type to the service layer, thank you Tomas.